# Dart Route error

Tags: dart, dart-pub, dart-html

I am experiencing an error which only shows up on my dev machine. Our dart application using Route; however, I am getting the following error:

```
    Uncaught Unhandled exception:
Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap' has no instance method 'pushState'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'pushState'
Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:0
Arguments: [null, "", "/index.html#browse"]
#0      Object._noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:42)
#1      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:45)
#2      Router._go (package:route/client.dart:153:22)
#3      Router.gotoPath (package:route/client.dart:139:7)
#4      Router.listen.<anonymous closure> (package:route/client.dart:111:13)
#5      wrap_event_listener.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:html:1215)
```

on all the routes, and it doesn't open the page. However, the application will open some other pages if it elapsed without any action more than 60 seconds which runs  `router.handle('/index.html#');` route. I even tested other routes in here and it worked (only on screensaver) but not on normal clicks on the route. 
I really confused what's going on here.

route handler:

```
router = new Router()
      ..addHandler(urls.home, showHome)
      ..addHandler(urls.browse, showBrowse)
      ..addHandler(urls.browseProducts, showBrowseProducts)
   ..listen();
```

URL:

```
final String index = '/index.html';
final String pctCls = r'[a-zA-Z0-9-_.~%]';
// TODO: fix home button
final home = new UrlPattern(index + r'#?');
final browse = new UrlPattern(index + r'#browse');
final browseProducts =
    new UrlPattern(index + r'#browse/(subcategory|search)/('+pctCls+r'+)');
```

Versions:

```
OS version: el-caption (OS X 10.11.3)
Chromium version: 39.0.2171.0
Dart VM version: 1.13.2 (Tue Jan  5 06:36:44 2016) on "macos_x64"
```

Thanks for your feedback in advance.

Comment: What browser and what Dart version are you and the other machines using?

Comment: Do you know how could I run the route example here:https://github.com/justinfagnani/route/example? I knew server is run by  ./dart (from bin folder) server.dart. How could I run the client? I am currently have some issue with this, and I want to make sure the basic route example works well

Comment: Still, what browser and Dart version are you using.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you run it in Chrome or any other browser than Dartium.

Comment: If you use `pub serve` (automatically launched by WebStorm for example, don't know about Atom) just copy the URL from Dartium to the other browser.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. What is "it" and where were you in Chrome?

Comment: the application stop in the first screen and never get further. Can you help me to run the route example? How can I run github.com/justinfagnani/route/example this?

Comment: How did you run it? Do you use `pub serve`?

Comment: Once I use pub server it run the test directory not example directory

Comment: No idea what that means. I guess you should work through the adart tutorials on http://dartlang.org

Comment: How do you run the client/server in https://github.com/justinfagnani/route/tree/master/example?

Comment: `pub serve example` and then open http://localhost:8080 (or whatever port `pub serve` prints when you run it)

Comment: `Serving route example on http://localhost:8080`
`Build completed successfully`
`[example] GET  → Could not find asset route|example.`
`[example] GET favicon.ico → Could not find asset route|example/favicon.ico.`

Comment: sorry, didn't look close enough. The example also contains a server. You also have to run this server (from another console) `dart example/server.dart`, Then reload the browser page.

Comment: How come no-one available to show me how to run example in the route package?